JavaScript Fetch Post request with file - formdata
I'm trying to send a POST request to this API, and it includes a file, specifically as multipart/form-data. I'm adding the file from the project directory, as it is a local file.
However, I am constantly alternating between 400 and 422 error codes as I try to debug.
async function storeDocument() {
  const apiUrl = 'api-url';

  if (!fs.existsSync('./EU AI Regulation final.pdf')) {
    throw new Error("File does not exist.");
}
  const fileStream = fs.createReadStream('./EU AI Regulation final.pdf');
  const formdata = new FormData();

  formdata.append("files", fileStream, "EU AI Regulation final.pdf");

  const response = await fetch(apiUrl, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formdata
  });

  if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`API request failed with status ${response.status}`);
  }
  const responseData = await response.json();
  return responseData;
}

Please help.
I tried changing the way the file is uploaded and sent to the api.
 formdata.append("files", fileInput.files[0], "EU AI Regulation final.pdf");
I was still getting errors with this. It's possible that I did not do it the right way. I would appreciate any assistance.

Are you running this in node.js or a browser? fileInput.files[0] is for a browser, the user has to select the file to upload in a file picker.

it's not for a browser. I'm guessing node.js? since i'm running it in vscode. what's the correct format in that case?

See the linked question.
